# Flutter Slider label overlap workaround

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There is an opened [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31042): `Slider.label` balloon is partially overlapped when placed near the top of the screen:

[image: screenshot_1]

In the issue comments, there is a discussion on how it can be fixed. But I don't understand how to implement a workaround until a fix is available.

In my app I added a `Container` above the `Slider`, but it is still overlapped when the `Slider` is in a *scrollable* `ListView`:

[image: screenshot_2]

So any ideas are welcome, preferably with code.

Comment: In the current version of Flutter this is fixed, so no answer needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a solution but a tricky**

When I see the problem I use a FloatingActionButton.extended with no-action to show inside its label the slider value.
(You can change the label position of the FloatingActionButton)

The main process consist in make visible or not the actionButton loading inside its label the slider value.
This is part of the code plus the tickMark changed to a vertical line:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo Custom Slider',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Custom Slider'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class tickMark_Line_Heigth extends SliderTickMarkShape {
  final double alturaTick;
  final double anchuraTick = 3;

  const tickMark_Line_Heigth(this.alturaTick);

  @override
  Size getPreferredSize({SliderThemeData sliderTheme, bool isEnabled}) {
    return Size.fromRadius(alturaTick);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {RenderBox parentBox,
      SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      Offset thumbCenter,
      bool isEnabled,
      TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.yellowAccent
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Offset centro = Offset(center.dx + 2, center.dy - alturaTick * 2);
    Rect puntos = centro & Size(anchuraTick, alturaTick * 4);
    canvas.drawRect(puntos, paint);
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: slider(0),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: slider(1),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: slider(2),
              flex: 1,
        ),
            Expanded(
              child: slider(3),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: slider(4),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: slider(5),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: slider(6),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: slider(7),
              flex: 1,
            ),
           ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: visibleActionButton
          ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                // Add your onPressed code here!
              },
              label: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Slide',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                  Text('$numSlider',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
                ],
              ),
              Text('$valueSlider',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
            ],
          ),
    backgroundColor: colorSlider(valueSlider),
  )
      : null,
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endTop,
    );
  }

  var valuesSlider = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  int valueSlider = 0;
  int numSlider = 0;
  bool visibleActionButton = false;

  Color colorSlider(valor) {
    Color color;
    switch (valor) {
      case 0:
      case 1:
        color = Colors.green;
        break;
      case 2:
      case 3:
        color = Colors.orange;
        break;
      default:
        color = Colors.red;
    }
    return color;
  }

  Widget slider(num) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
          trackHeight: 18,
          minThumbSeparation: 1,
          tickMarkShape: tickMark_Line_Heigth(4)),
      child: Slider(
        value: valuesSlider[num].toDouble(),
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        divisions: 5,
        activeColor: colorSlider(valuesSlider[num]),
        inactiveColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        label: '${valuesSlider[num]}',
        onChangeStart: (newValue) {
          setState(() {
            valueSlider = newValue.round();
            numSlider = num + 1;
            visibleActionButton = true;
          });
        },
        onChangeEnd: (newValue) {
          setState(() {
            valueSlider = 0;
            visibleActionButton = false;
          });
        },
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          setState(() {
            valuesSlider[num] = newValue.round();
            valueSlider = newValue.round();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```